# After drush arr - cannot login

Tags: drush

php 5.5.x, mysql 5.5, drush 5.x, drupal 7.33,

1. backed up drupal: 'drush ard default --destination=/manual_backup/backup_site_2014_11_15.tar'
2. switched to new 14.04 Ubuntu server, installed drush, import tar file:

   drush arr ./backup_site_2014_11_15.tar --destination=/var/www
3. edited /etc/hosts:

127.0.0.1 mysite.local

4. edited /etc/apache2/sites-available/default.conf

`ServerName  mysite.local
    Root            /var/www
    
        AllowOverride …`

5. Restarted apache

While 'drush cc all' I got the message:

> > PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function node_load() in /data/www/fdb/includes/menu.inc on line 593 <<
> >
> > Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error <<
> >
> > Error: Call to undefined  function node_load() in /data/www/fdb/includes/menu.inc on line 593 <<

Then I did 'drush dl registry_rebuild' and 'drush rr'.

Unfortunately I couldn't login. So I created a one time login which works.

I see all nodes, users, views, rules etc.

But after logging out I cannot login regularly.

Then I created a new password for user admin_ip via '/scripts/.create-new-pwd newpwd' and put the hash into the users database.

Finally I tried to login again but it didn't work.

How would you start to see what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Here are few tips:

- make sure your Drupal core has all the files in the right place (especially node module),
- make sure your imported database is in UTF-8 format,
- upgrade your Drupal core to the latest version (`drush fr && drush up drupal`)
- clear all your caches (`drush -y cc all`), including your memcached (`killall memcached`),
- rebuild your registry by using [Registry Rebuild](https://www.drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild) (which you already did),
- if you're using modules which are implementing `drupal_bootstrap()` (such as Secure Site), disable them,
- try disabling your PHP cache engines (such as XCache, Zend optimizer) to see if that's the problem,
- test it on different environment/machine,
- eventually restore your database from the point where it was working before